Identifying pole/zero frequencies in an op amp stabilization In-the-loop compensation circuit - Analog Devices article
I have been reading the following article by Analog, which discusses methods used to stabilize op amps when driving capacitive loads.
Analog: Practical Techniques to Avoid Instability Due to Capacitive Loading
One popular method discussed is the 'in the loop' compensation method, using a small resistor placed between the output of the op amp and the capacitive load and a feedback capacitor from the op amp's output to the inverting input. The circuit is shown below:

The feedback part of the circuit is shown below:

Two cases are then discussed in the article, where the pole and zero frequencies are deduced by finding the time constants for \$C_L\$ and \$C_F\$. The pole and zero frequencies for \$C_L\$ are found as:
$$\text{Pole Frequency} = \frac{1}{2\pi (R_O + R_X) C_L}$$
$$\text{Zero Frequency} = \frac{1}{2\pi R_X C_L}$$
I am having trouble following how the zero frequency has been obtained. \$R_F\$ and \$R_\text{IN}\$ disappear due to \$R_X << R_F\$, and \$R_O << R_\text{IN}\$.
I recently bought Christophe Basso's book, 'The Fast track to determining transfer functions of linear circuits'. I have been trying to use the FACTS method to determine the time constants in order to perhaps gain an understanding of the reasoning used in the Analog article. I began by setting the op amp output to zero and finding the resistances looking into each of the capacitor terminals. My working is shown below:

I then shorted \$C_F\$ and repeated the method for \$C_L\$, shown in my working below:

My problem is, I still have no idea how the zero frequency is derived in the article.

Hello, glad to count you among my readers : ) I looked at this configuration with the FACTs at work in an answer given on August 2021. Let me know if you can follow the flow or need additional help.

I think, there is an error in the refrenced article.
The pole frequency was confused with the zero (as far as the closed-loop gain Acl is concerned).
Using the simplifications as mentioned in the article (case 1), the feedback function is
VB/VA=Hf=[Rx+(1/sCL)]/[Ro+Rx+(1/sCL)]
From this, the closed loop gain of the opamp is
Acl=1/Hf=[1+(Ro+Rx)sCL]/[1+sRxCL]
Hence, the zero is at wz=1/(R0+Rx)CL and the pole wp=1/RxCL
EDIT/Explanation: The feedback scheme as given in the figure is based on the principle of "frequency compensated voltage division" with phase enhancement below the pole frequency. Here is a "rule of thumb" for dimensioning the circuit:

Assumptions: RF>>Rx, CL>>CF and Rx=Rout

Requirement: k(Rout+Rx)CL=(Rout+RF)CF with k=(1...1.3).


In this case, the zero fz will be somewhat smaller than the pole frequency (fz app. equal to fp/k).

Thanks. I can understand that aspect of the feedback function. But there is also feedback from RF. So we ignore that then?

@ Paul - no, Rf is not ignored. Look at the right part of the equation at the end of my EDIT.

@ Paul - to stabilize the system it is nessecary to place the zero in te vicinity of - but somewhat below - the pole frequency (see the free selectable factor k in the equation). Therefore, it makes no sense to consider resistors which contribute only a liitle to the relevant time constants. That is the background of the used simplifications

Hi LvW. Ok, I'll take another look..

Here's your image where I've highlighted the two components that make the zero: -

If you worked out the transfer function you'd get this: -
$$TF_Z = \dfrac{\frac{1}{sC_L}}{R_X + \frac{1}{sC_L}} = \dfrac{1}{1+sC_LR_X}$$
What makes that equation zero is when s is very large i.e. the equation reduces to \$\dfrac{1}{sC_LR_X}\$. We can then say that the zero frequency is \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi C_LR_X}\$

Hi Andy. Yes, but isn't the transfer function a function of Ro and CF also? Why are these left out?

Because we are targeting the zeros and those two components are clear candidates.

I think, that Andy aka`s approach did not yet take into account the fact that the lowpass signal is fed back to the amplifier (see the equivalent diagram for VB(VA).

LvW: Yes, the two feedback elements are not being included. I understand that Rx and CL are a low-pass filter, but why should the analysis of a zero be limited to these two local components? This is why I was trying to implement FACTs method, to deduce all the time constants. I was wondering if Verbal Kint could have a look?

@ Paul - as far as I have understood your question you was referring to the results for the case 1 with all the simplifications as given in the ref. document. Of course, the results are different without these simplifications. If such simplifications are appropriate (or not) depends on the specific applications.

@ Paul - please, see my edit (explanations). This may answer your question regarding the applied simplifications. The feedback elements must be chosen according to some specific requirements in order to stabilize the circuit as desired.

As indicated in the comments section, I gave a detailed answer about the transfer function linking nodes A and B in SE a few years ago. I used the FACTs to deliver the exact expression.
For the purpose of this post, I have updated my answer with the determination of poles and zeroes in the final application around the op-amp. The first TF linking nodes A and B is derived below:

I then compare the exact simulation results from SIMetrix with the full-blown expression and its simplified version, in which I involve the low-\$Q\$ approximation:

Then I check the response at the op-amp output (before \$R_{out}\$) now that I have the TF linking nodes A and B:

However, in the end, we want the output at the load node, across \$C_L\$ and \$R_L\$. Without considering \$R_L\$, we can reuse the exact transfer function we have derived and add an output pole involving \$C_L\$ alone:

I can further simplify, drop one pole and one zero (\$C_L\$ no longer contributes a zero for instance), to end up with a simplified expression featuring two poles (we have two energy-storing elements) and one single zero:

As a preliminary conclusion, the determination of the TF linking nodes A to B, is a good exercise and it leads to the exact voltage delivered by the op-amp output at node A in the SIMetrix template. However, more work is needed to derive the complete transfer function of the closed-loop system for a response sensed across \$C_L\$ and \$R_L\$. I did use an approximation in the end - it's getting late : ) but, the best nerdy approach is to rewrite the time constants across the entire network, including the op-amp and its open-loop gain, then identify the poles and zeroes. If time permit, I will do it later.

Hi. Oh, thanks for that thorough analysis. I did actually find your previous post some years ago on the same circuit. I'll have a look through. I have your book here to work through too.

Hello, perfect, good luck with this exercise then ^_^ I let you judge whether this is the answer you did expect to acknowledge it in SE. Cheers.
